# Is it possible to disable one of the valueSource in a parameterizedTest?

Tags: junit5, parameterized-tests

I am using JUnit 5 and I have a test case like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(Strings = {a , b , c})
void example(String letter){
// do something
}
```

the **c** case is unhandled for now, so is it possible to use @Disabled to ignore only the c case not the whole test suite?
Or maybe suggest another way to take c case out of my smoke tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't disable a particular value in ParameterizedTest simply remove the value and run